# Copying files in fileset if a file of the same name exists with a specific suffix at the end

Tags: ant

I am using a third party build script creates minified js files with the minified file called 'someFile.js' and an unminified version called 'someFile.js.uncompressed.js'. I need one of my tasks in the build.xml to copy only the js files that have a partner '.uncompressed.js' file to another location. For example, given a directory structure like this:

```
- rootDirectory
  - minified.js
  - minified.js.uncompressed
  - unminified.js
  - anotherDirectory
    - anotherMinified.js
    - anotherMinified.js.uncompressed.js
    - unminified.js
    - anotherUnminified.js
```

the destination directory should end up like this:

```
- rootDirectory
  - minified.js
  - anotherDirectory
    - anotherMinified.js
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with ant? I am using ant 1.8.1.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an Ant [`<present>` selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect) to do this.  For example:

```
<copy todir="dest">
    <fileset dir="src">
        <present targetdir="src">
            <mapper type="glob" from="*" to="*.uncompressed.js" />
        </present>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

In this case the `targetdir` in the selector is the same as the root directory of the fileset.

What this does is copy any file in the `src` directory tree where a file with the same name, with `.uncompressed.js` appended also present.

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom [scriptselector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#scriptselector) for your fileset.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── src
│   └── rootDirectory
│       ├── anotherDirectory
│       │   ├── anotherMinified.js
│       │   ├── anotherMinified.js.uncompressed
│       │   ├── anotherUnminified.js
│       │   └── unminified.js
│       ├── minified.js
│       ├── minified.js.uncompressed
│       └── unminified.js
└── target
    └── rootDirectory
        ├── anotherDirectory
        │   └── anotherMinified.js
        └── minified.js
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="copy-files">

   <target name="copy-files">
      <copy todir="target">
         <fileset dir="src">
            <scriptselector language="javascript">
               importClass(java.io.File);
               var testForFile = new File("src/" + filename + ".uncompressed");
               self.setSelected(testForFile.exists());
            </scriptselector>
         </fileset>
      </copy>
   </target>

   <target name="clean">
      <delete dir="target"/>
   </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- This should work without the need for additional jars. Javascript is supported by modern JVMs.